# Adding CSRF protection to simple comment forms in Django

Tags: python, django, blogs

I have blog comment forms in Django and I would like to know the following:

1. Should I add CSRF to the forms?
2. If I want to use the simple "render_comment_form" method, how do I add it?
3. If I can't add it like that, what is the best practice for doing it?

Each tutorial or discussion on the subject seems to have a different approach, and I am not certain I understand how it all works.

Comment: The handling of CSRF protection was changed in django 1.2 so it would be good to provide the django version you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer assumes that you are using Django 1.2:

1. Yes! You should protect all your data that is sent by POST requests to the server against CSRF attacks.
2. You don't need to add the token yourself. This is already done by django. Have a look at the [default template that is used by the `render_comment_form` tag](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/comments/templates/comments/form.html) and you will see, that the `csrf_token` is already included. You can overwrite this template in your project and including the CSRF token into it is as easy as writing `{% csrf_token %}` into the form.
3. There is a way to protect your forms even if you don't set the tokens in the templates. Have a look at [django's documentation about that topic](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#legacy-method). But this method is marked as a ***legacy*** method so it's not recommended to use that - it's only provided for backwards compatibility with versions of Django earlier than 1.2.